# .net WebService URL Issue

Tags: web-services

I have a WebService written in VB.net with couple of webmethods and I published the WebService to the IIS.

The URL for wsdl is http://mywebservice/DataPort/portData.asmx?wsdl

There are couple of Java applications that are consuming the above mentioned webservice.

The Java team wants the URL to end with portData?wsdl instead of portData.asmx?wsdl

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You tell them "no". There's no reason that they need it. Java (Axis, at least) does just fine with .asmx?wsdl. Tell them to try it and see.

Comment: I agree with John, however if they protest then just configure a handler for that path.

Comment: Yeah, but in ASMX services, I'm not sure how he'd get that path to go to the service. Maybe a redirect?

Comment: Also, what version of IIS and .NET are you running, and on what OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210519003519/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011404-1.aspx) gives you an idea of how IIS handles requests.  You'll want to setup an HTTP Request Handler.

In your web.config you'll need to configure the handler's section.

```
<httpHandlers>
     <add verb="GET,POST" path="*" type="Namespace.Class,Namespace" />
     <add verb="GET,POST" path="/" type="Namespace.Class,Namespace" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Then in IIS for the Virtual Directory your web-service is hosted in you'll need to go to Properties->Home Directory->Configuration->Mappings and associate the dll for your version of ASP.NET to whatever path you've specified.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at the similar [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609125/call-an-iis-web-service-without-the-asmx-extension)? Might be of some help.