# CGI and .net webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, cgi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call an IIS Web Service without the .asmx extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609125/call-an-iis-web-service-without-the-asmx-extension)

We have to recieve an incoming call from client's wbeserver
It is looking for url webservice/somethig.cgi in our webserver
How can I map this to our .net webservice?

Comment: [got the answer from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609125/call-an-iis-web-service-without-the-asmx-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Use the HttpHandlers to handle the .cgi files.

Whenever the .cgi file has been requested. Check its name as you mentioned here the CGI name is "Somethig" so correspondingly call the webserivce or redirect to any other page which calls the webservice u want.

ref.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/civa_kumar2000/HTTPHandlersinASP.NET11282005003115AM/HTTPHandlersinASP.NET.aspx